# RecyclerView - scroll one screen up or down (not based on adapter position)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Having a RecyclerView with items with (very) different heights, how can I scroll 1 screen down (or up)? 
So after scrolling 1 screen down, the data is shown that was just below the data on the current screen.

As an extreme example: when I have a very large first data item and the scroll y-position is 0, then scrolling 1 screen down would mean in this case to show the next/remaining part of the data of the first item.

There are a number of ways that might help.

- Using the adapter position. This does not work when the items (in the adapter) are fairly large.
- Using the percentage. For example, using the following methods with the ScrollOffset, ScrollExtent and ScrollRange. OK, how to use this percentage? Is the percentage based on the average size/height of a data item? See below the list.
- Using scrollTo( 0, y). How to find the next 'y'?

The mehods of the ScrollOffset, Extent and Range are:

```
int offset = recyclerView.computeVerticalScrollOffset();
int extent = recyclerView.computeVerticalScrollExtent();
int range = recyclerView.computeVerticalScrollRange();
float percentage = (100.0f * offset / (float)(range - extent));
```

So, is there a way to scroll 1 screen down, independent of the size of the data (row) items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrolling by the height of the view should do it, no? Tested quickly on a recyclerview inside a scrollview.

I.e. `view.post(() -> view.scrollBy(0, view.getHeight()));`

Comment: Thank you! Even without the scrollview, this works ok on the recyclerview. The getHeight() on the recyclerview gives the same value as the computeVerticalScrollExtent().